# Bigmemory in R and Server

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a big matrix in R and fill it with predicted values from a fitted model.  I created the matrix on a remote server and am filling it in using a *for* loop.

```
library("bigmemory")
pred = filebacked.big.matrix(nrow=50000,ncol=150000,backingfile="pred.bin",descriptorfile="pred.desc",backingpath="~/pred")
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    pred[i,] = as.vector(intercept+beta%*%data[i,])
}
```

The actual *.bin* file is on a remote server.  Yet the process of filling in the matrix still takes up a lot of physical memory on my computer.  How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I HOPE I UNDERSTOOD YOU RIGHT!

Filling in the matrix takes a lot of physical memory on your computer because the calculations are made on you computer.

If i see it right, you could think about it that way:
*If i ask you to calculate something and write it down on my sheet of paper, you still have the whole calculation-process in "your brain";But the results are on my paper;*

Well, how could you avoid this:
set up an r runtime on the Serve r- and let the server calculate !
The Server should do the "fill in data-process";